# (MS Excel) How do I use sumifs or sumproduct on an array like this that has 3 criteria?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have tried sumifs and sumproducts to try get the results I need which is to sum the values if the 3 criteria of: column A=prescribed start date, column B=prescribed end date, and the column headers = the person name, is met. Below is the spreadsheet:

[image: Payroll - Extra]

This is a sample formula:

```
=SUMIFS('Payroll - Extra'!C2:C1048576,'Payroll - Extra'!A2:A1048576,"='Payroll Tables and Settings'!S3",'Payroll - Extra'!B2:B1048576,"='Payroll Tables and Settings'!T3",'Payroll - Extra'!C1,'Payslip - Extra'!A3)
```

The formula is entered in the #VALUE cell in the image below:
[image: Payslip - Extra]

[Sample file](https://ufile.io/xvzyj)

Comment: Your `sum_range` is column C **only**.  And you refer to data that you don't show in your screen shot.  And screenshots are not simple to transfer to worksheets.  All that makes it hard to reproduce your problem. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question; or upload a worksheet (with sensitive information removed) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Added the file at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the `VALUE` error in your formula is that your third criteria_range is not the same size as the `sum_range`, which is a requirement for `SUMIFS`.

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, you are only SUMming column C (John).

To use SUMIFS, you need to have the sum_range be the proper column.  One way of doing that is by using the INDEX function.  Use MATCH to determine the proper column, then enter `0` for the row argument and all of the rows for that column will be returned.  See HELP for the INDEX function.

You should also, as we mentioned in your previous question, remove the cell references from inside the quotes.  I made them absolute so they would not increment, but you can change that.

So one way of rewriting the formula that you have in your screenshot in the cell showing `Value` is:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Payroll - Extra'!$C$2:$J$1048576,0, MATCH($A3,'Payroll - Extra'!$C$1:$J$1,0)),'Payroll - Extra'!A2:A1048576,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!$S$3,'Payroll - Extra'!B2:B1048576,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!$T$3)
```

The following should work similarly, and is a bit simpler and shorter:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Payroll - Extra'!$C:$J,0, MATCH($A3,'Payroll - Extra'!$C$1:$J$1,0)),'Payroll - Extra'!$A:$A,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!$S$3,'Payroll - Extra'!$B:$B,'Payroll Tables and Settings'!$T$3)
```

Comment: Okay it works. Been stuck on this for a long time I really appreciate your help these past 2 days

Comment: Sadly this error pops out: "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated." If I integrate everything together

Comment: Most computers in the office are using a 32-bit operating system and I believe only 2gb of ram can be used by excel in this point. I am also afraid once the file has been put into day-to-day practice it will come a point where the data will exceed its limits

Comment: I have confirmed that using the first formula is causing the error because of its computational complexity.

Comment: @MarcSantos The 2nd formula I provided is equivalent. Just use that since it seems to work better. Failing that, a different approach will be required.  How many rows of data do you really have?  Whole column references are not usually necessary; and VBA may have an advantage also. If your data is truly huge, Excel might not even be the right tool.

Comment: Not so much really I would say in its life it would use around 130,000 to 250,000 rows in 10 years for the daily time record of the employees. For the ones with the sumifs and sumproducts, I would estimate around 5,000 to 10,000 for 10 years worth of data.

Comment: I realized the range on the formula here was too broad when I only needed 1 column for the sum range of the sumproduct. It caused the inefficiency and very very long computation times. I fixed it already. Thanks

Comment: @MarcSantos Glad you have it working. Because of the way they work, if it can be used, `SUMIFS` is generally more efficient, and faster, than is `SUMPRODUCT`.  Whether that makes a difference in perceived times depends on the complexity and size of the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUMPRODUCT`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Payroll - Extra'!$C$2:$V$1048576)*('Payroll - Extra'!$C$1:$V$1=A3)*('Payroll - Extra'!A2:A1048576='Payroll Tables and Settings'!S3)*('Payroll - Extra'!B2:B1048576='Payroll Tables and Settings'!T3))
```

Comment: Nope same problem :/

Comment: My guess is that the sumifs and sumproduct cannot handle columns as criterias or maybe all criteria has to be in rows or in columns and cannot be a mix of 2

Comment: @MarcSantos - In `SUMIFS` criteria could be a range. Are you sure there are values matching all three conditions?

Comment: The criteria can be range yeah, but in this case it errors. That is the problem i'm facing. Yeah I am positive there are values matching the three conditions. I tested the problem and the problem lies in the last criteria, the person's name. I believe because it is a column. If I remove the last criteria it works, but then it will not work as I want it to work

Comment: @MarcSantos - Wait a minute, where are the names listed in the `Payroll - Extra` sheet, is it in `Column C` or in `Row 1`.

Comment: @MarcSantos - If sum range is `'Payroll - Extra'!C2:C1048576` then criteria_range for name cannot be `'Payroll - Extra'!C1:C1048576`.

Comment: It is in Row 1 as shown in the image above. So its similar to a n x m matrix where n is the dates and m is the names of the people and the values are their corresponding pays for that date range

Comment: @MarcSantos - And what's the range?

Comment: If you refer to the 2nd image, that is the corresponding payslip of that employee. So the criteria is that, the name in the column should match that of the payslip while matching the date range criterias. So you can say the name criteria is one is to one. The "range" you are asking for the would be C1:ZZZZ1048576 but it still has the same error. It is not top to bottom but from left to right

Comment: @MarcSantos - Can you name your images with sheet names in the question. Its very confusing whether it is `Payroll - Extra`, `Payroll Tables and Settings` or `Payslip - Extra`

Comment: I will put a link of my excel file so you guys can play with it there.

Comment: @MarcSantos - That will be even better.

Comment: Added the file at the bottom of the post

Comment: Thanks a lot this works great as well. Appreciate the effort and the solution